# Doctrine fetch join

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm

First I will give an example with some pseudo code and then I will explain what is the problem. Let me say I have two entities User and Phonenumber. Their relation is one-to-many. In my UserRepository I can have something like that:

```
class UserRepository
{
    public function getUser($id, $type)
    {
        $users = $this->createQuery("SELECT u, p FROM User u JOIN u.phonenumbers p
            WHERE u.id = :id AND p.type = :type")
            ->setParameters(array(
                'id' => $id,
                'type' => $type,
            ))
            ->getResult();
        return $users[0];
    }
}
```

In my app if I have something like:

```
$user = $userRepo->getUser(1, 'home');
var_dump($user->getPhonenumbers()); // here phonenumbers collection is ok

$user = $userRepo->getUser(1, 'work');
var_dump($user->getPhonenumbers()); // Here phonenumbers collection is wrong.
                                // It's exactly the same as the previous one.
```

So my questions is: Is it possible to use fetch join (with different criteria) and to get the proper collection each time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fetch joining and filtering a collection are not things that work together quite well. Here's how you should do it:

```
SELECT 
    u, p 
FROM 
    User u 
JOIN 
    u.phonenumbers p
JOIN
    u.phonenumbers p2
WHERE 
    u.id = :id 
    AND 
    p2.type = :type
```

This applies filtering on the second joined (and not hydrated) `p2`, which results in correct hydration and filtering.

Comment: For the moment I end up using Query::HINT_REFRESH, which I believe will have some performance impact, but definitely I will check your solution. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score -2):

Use querybuilder, it is much simpler.

```
public function getUser($id, $type)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder("u")
        ->leftJoin("u.Phonenumbers", "p", "WITH", "p.type=:type")
        ->where("u.id=:id")
        ->setParameters(.....)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getOneOrNullResult() ;
}
```

Comment: The example is just a pseudo code. The problem is in doctrine's behavior, not in the provided code.

Comment: Still the same, use leftJoin and WITH statement no matter how you build queries.

Comment: This example is not doing a fetch join, so Phonenumbers will be lazy loaded. WITH does not do both a fetch join and a filter. The correct answer is Ocramius', doing two joins, one for filter, one for fetch.