# Select filtered collections of multiple entities using Doctrine join

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to select two entities using doctrine join.

```
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT u, a FROM User u JOIN u.addresses a WHERE a.city =      'Berlin'");
$users = $query->getResult();
```

I have followed the [documentation here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins), the query work well but I didn't manage how to get the second entity.

I tried this but it load the hole address array

```
foreach($users as $user){
   echo($user->getAddresses();//this contains all addresses not the filtered address
}
```

The documentation mentioned something about hydrated variable User#address but not how to get it.

User.orm.yml

```
 Home\DinnerBundle\Entity\User:
  type: entity
  table: user
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator: { strategy: AUTO }
  fields:
    first:
      type: string
    last:
      type: string
  oneToMany:
      addresses:
        targetEntity: Address
        mappedBy: user
```

Address.orm.yml

```
  Home\DinnerBundle\Entity\Address:
  type: entity
  table: address
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator: { strategy: AUTO }
  fields:
    id:
      type: integer
      nullable: true
    street_line:
      type: text
    city:
      type: string
    state:
      type: string
  manyToOne:
     user:
       targetEntity: User
       inversedBy: addresses
       joinColumn:
          name: user_id
          referencedColumnName: id
```

Comment: Hello, it would help us if you posted your entities code and what exactly are you getting as an output? Also, you should take a look to the queryBuilder

Comment: @Splendonia I have posted my code. Also I didn't find an example on how to achieve it using query builder.

Comment: foreach($users as $user){
   echo($user->getAddress()->getCity());
}  Post the output of this, also, the code you posted doesn't not reflect the User and Adress entities which is the ones that you're querying.

Comment: What Doctrine version is this?

Comment: This looks similar, although the accepted answer looks unconfirmed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13603054/doctrine-fetch-join

Comment: 2 point what?  This area of behaviour does seem to have been tweaked in the 2.x releases.

Answer (score 0):

With QueryBuilder the code would be something like this:

```
$results = $em->getRepository('YourBundle:User')
                ->createQueryBuilder('user')
                ->join('user.address', 'address')
                ->where('address.city = :city_name')
                ->setParameter('city_name', "Berlin")
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult();
```

NOTE: `->setParameter('city_name', "Berlin")` //only applies when there's only a parameter, when you have several you need to use `->setParameters(array('param_name' => $param_value, 'param_name_1' => $param_value_1))`

The documentation is [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html)

Comment: my problem is about accessing address object (which is hydrated) from $results and not in creating the query it self.

Comment: Like I said in the comment, please post the entities (User, Address) and the output of $results you're getting.

Comment: Don't know if it's relevant, but the Question selects both `user` and `address`, i.e. does an eager fetch.  My digging leaves me uncertain whether that's a crucial difference.

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you are using the entity manager query builder?
It will automatically hydrate your joined entities.

Here is a piece of code:

```
public function query(){
    $queryBuilder = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    $queryBuilder->addSelect('user')
                ->join('user.address','address')
                ->where('address.city = :cityParameter')
                ->setParameter('cityParameter', 'Berlin');
    $query = $queryBuilder->getQuery();
    $result =  $query->getResult();

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: My problem isn't about using DQL or query builder, but about how I access to the hydrated object?

Comment: simply by calling: $user->getAddress();

Comment: this will get all Addresses it doesn't contains filtered addresses with city=Berlin

Comment: Did you meant that each user will have many records of addresses? if so then it is $collection = $user->getAddresses() , this will return a doctrine collection which you can filter. $filteredAddressCollection = $collection->filter(function($elm) use ($cityParameter){return $elm->getCity()==$cityParameter; }

Comment: Yes exactly but whats the point of using select (a, b) while I can't use it ??? The doctrine documentation really sucks.

Comment: the select filter only the users which have specific address, not filter the addresses on a user.

Comment: Don't know if it's relevant, but the Question selects both `user` and `address`, i.e. does an eager fetch.  My digging leaves me uncertain whether that's a crucial difference.

Comment: Also, this isn't the answer but there is a nicer getAddresses filtering syntax which works at a SQL level for entities that have not yet been loaded: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections